# Image of Like in Iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-like

I want to add a "Like" feature in my app and put Facebook's Like image (it has no connection to the actual like in facebook).
Is that allowed ? using the "Like" Image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not allowed by copyright

Answer (score 0):

This is something related to adding the like functionality in iOS app

if you were looking for same then try it

[this is quite good tutorial if ray wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app)